# Use an Observable working with another Observable

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase, observable

I'm trying to show information, like that :
user-settings.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="(_user | async) as user">
  <div fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <h3>{{ user.surname + ' ' + user.name }}</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <b>Email : </b>
      {{ user.email }}
    </span>
  </div>
[...]
```

Actually, in TS I do :

```
_user = this.db.collection('user').doc("IDENTIFICATION").valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }) as Observable<User>;
```

problem is that IDENTIFICATION is statics so I tried to do :

`user-settings.component.ts`

```
_user: Observable<User> = this.getUser();
[...]
getUser() {
  var userTempo: Observable<User>;

  this.authService.getUser().subscribe(user => {
    userTempo = this.db.collection('user').doc(user.uid).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }) as Observable<User>;
    console.log(user.uid);
  });
  return userTempo;
}
```

to know `this.authService.getUser()` is comming from :

`authService.ts`

```
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}
[...]
getUser() {
  return this.afAuth.user;
}
```

In this configuration, `_user` returns undefined, so nothing can be showed.
Does anyone have an idea?
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return an Observable, but what your returning is an object, as you’ve subscribed to it and assigned userTempo an object.

```ts
getUser(): Observable<User> {
  return this.authService.getUser().map(user => {
    console.log(user.uid);
    return this.db.collection('user').doc(user.uid).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
  });
}
```

If `this.db.collection('user').doc(user.uid).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })` returns an Observable then you will have to do this.

```ts
  getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.authService.getUser().switchMap(user => {
      return this.db.collection('user').doc(user.uid).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
    }).map(response => {
      return response;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but actually, I only return a double Observable like this : `getUser(): Observable<Observable<User>> {[...]}`, but how can I only return a simple Observable like this : `Observable<User>` ? (because the actual version works, but it is not optimised)

Comment: ```getUser(): Observable<Observable<User>> {
    return this.authService.getUser().map(user => {
      const userTempo = this.db.collection('user').doc(user.uid).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }) as Observable<User>;
      console.log(user.uid);
      return userTempo;
    });
  }```

Comment: Yes your suggestion returns `Observable<Observable<User>>`  and so, I'm trying to make it return `Observable<User>`

Comment: Oh i know why, I think its because your casting the data as an `Observable<User>`. Remove the following `as Observable<User>;` from `userTempo` and try that. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Can i confirm, what is the return type of this call? `b.collection('user').doc(user.uid).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })`

Comment: `getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.authService.getUser().map(user => {
      const userTempo = this.db.collection('user').doc(user.uid).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
      console.log(user.uid);
      return userTempo;
    });
  }`

Comment: We are close ! But this time it tell : `Cannot assign type 'Observable<Observable<{ id: string; }>>' to type 'Observable<User>'.`

Comment: `b.collection('user').doc(user.uid).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })` returns an `Observable<{ id: string; }>` it is why I pushed it into Observable<User> and usually that work

Comment: I'm confused, if that line returns `Observable<{ id: string; }>` then what does `getUser()` return, surely `getUser()` is your type `User`. I've updated my answer assuming that the line `this.db.collection('user').doc(user.uid).valueChanges` returns Observable<User>. If it doesn't work can you post code somewhere for me to look ? (like Stackblitz)

Comment: Thank you ! the second version worked very well ! I have to learn more about map method ! Thank you for you time VVS !